# Yahoo's second day font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Yahoo is currently changing its logo's font every day and I particularly liked this font:

[image]

Would anyone know if this font is a custom development of Yahoo or if it is some (possibly paid) public font?
I tried myfonts.com but it couldnt identify it.

Answer (score 5):

Someone is welcome to prove me wrong as this is not authoritative, but I believe that it's a custom job. Here's why:

The 'o' glyphs are different. That rules out most basic free fonts and indicates either custom or a more recent OpenType font.

The second 'o' glyph is slightly larger than the first and moves upward just a bit. This fits with the current Yahoo! logo as well as the other logos released so far:

[image: Original logo]
[image: Logo 1]
[image: Logo 3]
[image: Logo 4]

If this observation is correct and not just incidental, it means that, at the very least, a commercial font was customized.

Finally, most fonts that would have an 'ah' ligature like that wouldn't do a 'y' or an 'o' like that. Take a look through [MyFonts' list of script fonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag%3Ascript/fonts/) - you'll see that if the ascender of an 'h' is looped, the 'o' will typically be looped as well, or it'll show some kind of indication of where the pen was placed on the paper and where it was removed. Same deal with the 'Y'.

If you're looking for some great script fonts, browse MyFonts or just check out [Sudtipos](http://www.sudtipos.com/home) - they do really great work.

It's possible that they just got lucky and found something that fit their general logo scheme (big Y, small A, big H, small O, larger and more elevated O) really well, but the more likely explanation is customized commercial font or something made from scratch. I'm leaning towards the latter.

Comment: Among professional script fonts it's relatively common to make extensive use of opentype features such as contextual alternates in order to change the appearance of a character based on the character before or after it.

That said, I haven't found a conclusive match yet.

I think it (the day 2 logo) would make a good logo for Yahoo, by the way.

Comment: Are the o's really different? That was my first thought, but it looks to me like it's just larger and elevated on the second o.

Comment: @user1803405 - I'd say they are different. [Here they are at about the same size](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pbZLv.jpg) - the counters might be exactly the same, but the right side of the purple 'o' is thicker and the red 'o' is thicker at about 7:00 and thinner at 12:00.

Comment: @Brendan I see.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's likely to be a custom design, it's possible that it drew some inspiration from fonts such as [**Olivier**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/letters-numbers/olivier/) by Letters&Numbers.

[image]

At any rate, it's a rather nice-looking font.

[image]

Comment: Good find! I hadn't seen that one.